# How do you test what block is underneath you?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to test if any player is on a certain block. I want to kill them if they are standing on that certain block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`execute`'s `detect` syntax is useful for this.

In 1.11 and below:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ sponge * /kill @a[c=1]
```

In 1.12 and above:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ sponge * /kill @s
```

This will kill anyone standing on sponge. The `*` is where you would put the block state, e.g for `wool color=red` or `stone variant=granite`.